# Firebase - FriendlyPix git sample - does the database need to be manually created?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've downloaded the FirebasePix sample - the instructions do not say anything about creating the database on Firebase.
Does the database need to be created?
Where can I find instructions.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to the Firebase console then database section, there you can add the different nodes that you are gonna use in the project.

But usually you just connect to the database in the code and send data from the code that you write.

In Firebase Pix (ios app), an example is this: https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix-ios/blob/master/FriendlyPix/FPUploadViewController.swift

Here he connects to the database:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
```

then creates node `post` with `pushid`:

```
 let postRef = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId()
```

then later in the same file he adds the following data:

```
 let data = ["full_url": fullUrl ?? "", "full_storage_uri": fullstorageUri,
              "thumb_url": thumbUrl ?? "", "thumb_storage_uri": thumbstorageUri, "text": trimmedComment ?? "",
              "author": FPUser.currentUser().author(), "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp()] as [String: Any]
  postRef.setValue(data)
```

so in the database you would have:

```
post
  pushid
   full_url: url
   full_storage_uri: storageuri
   thumb_url: url
   //etc
```

Comment: I run the app and get an error on the upload. "Error uploading image". FIRStorageErrrorDomain.

Comment: check your firebase storage rules or just open an issue in github and show him the full error